# Visual Studios 6 Enterprise to VS 2005/2008/2010 Upgrade

Tags: visual-studio

Good Evening,

To all who know Microsoft's upgrade policy. I own VS6 Enterprise. Is VS6 Enterprise eligible for upgrade? I also own pro vs 2005/2008 but would like the enterprise edition upgraded. I have found posts that say yes and no. What is the real policy?

Thanks again for your comments. I love stack over flow!

Brennan

Comment: What do you want to upgrade to? Do you want to get another license for Visual Studio 2008? You can qualify for upgrade pricing on Visual Studio 2008 Standard if you have a license for one of the free Visual Studio Express editions (as mentioned in the Before You Buy section at http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Visual-Studio-2008-Standard-Edition-Upgrade/product/99E69042).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: Microsoft Licensing is confusing as hell.  The best way to get a good answer on this:

1. [**Go here to the Visual Studio Pricing Page**](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/howtobuy/default.mspx)
2. Click the **Price Comparison Chart** tab
3. Click the **Request a call back** link

This way you'll get someone who can give you a **definite** answer calling you back (same day when I had a question a few weeks back).

Answer (score -1):

My guess is "no". It's like asking what's the upgrade policy from Windows 95 to Windows 7. Too many generations in the middle.

Comment: We all can guess... but what's the actual policy?

Comment: This is an educated guess based on some upgrade questions I had over the years with Microsoft (i.e. Biztalk Server 01 to 07 - NO, SQL Server 05 to 08 - YES). Regardless, this question does not suit this forum as it is not a matter of opinion. As Nick said below, just call Microsoft and find out. Oh, and it helps if you work for a big Microsoft client - the answer tends to change... :)